# Funcionamieto de callback javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Quería saber si alguien me podría ayudar a comprender el funcionamiento de esta función *callback*, estoy aprendiendo sobre este tema y se me es algo confuso en determinadas situaciones. La duda puntual es que hace la función `getResults()`, no logro entender el `console.log` en el que al final se llama al parametro *results*, **¿de donde saca ese valor?**, al finalizar el codigo se llama a otro `console.log` en el que se pasa el valor de *query* y se pasa la funcion *callback*, pero a esta ultima no se le pasa ningun argumento, por eso no logro comprender bien **de donde saca el valor de *results***, espero se logre entender mi pregunta, gracias.

```js
let serverRequest = (query, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let response = query + "full!";
        callback(response);
    }, 500);
}

let getResults = (results) => {
    console.log("Response from the server: " + results);
}

console.log(serverRequest("The glass is half ", getResults));
```

Comment: No lo coloco como respuesta debido a que no estoy seguro, pero como tal cuando a getResults le asignas results. este va a mostrar lo que contenga getResults , como tal la función callback la haces cuando haces "=>" eso es el callback, visto de otro modo seria como retornar el valor, pero no es como la función return, es la respuesta que se genera a una petición dicho de mejor manera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vayamos por parte, primero analizamos el `serverRequest()`

```
let serverRequest = (query, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let response = query + "full!";
        callback(response);
    }, 500);
}
```

> El método `serverRequest()`, recibe como parámetro una "*query*" y un
>   "*callback*", a primera vista no dice mucho, pero analizando el
>   código, podemos ver que la `query` es un *string* y *callback* es una
>   `función`. Tengamos esto en mente para los pasos siguientes.

---

Ahora analicemos `getResults()`

```
let getResults = (results) => {
    console.log("Response from the server: " + results);
}
```

> El método `getResults ()`, recibe como parámetro un "*results*" y lo imprime, aca es donde se te presenta el problema, y te propongo que re nombremos *results* por "*response*" para que la imagen mental de flujo te sea mas sencilla.

---

Ahora analicemos el llamado de la función `serverRequest()`

```
console.log(serverRequest("The glass is half ", getResults));
```

Como habíamos dicho, *`serverRequest`* recibe un *string* y una *función*, lo cual se cumple en este caso. La función que recibe en este caso es *`getResults`*, que espera un parámetro, un dato a tener en cuenta es que *`getResults`* no tiene los paracentesis "()", lo cual indica que no se ejecuta en esa linea, sino que se pasa la función como referencia.

Luego dentro de *`serverRequest`* el parámetro pasa a llamarse "callback" pero por detrás sigue siendo *getResults*, por lo que al momento de hacer `callback(response);` le estas pasando el parámetro "response" a *getResults* y ejecutándola.

Answer (score 1):

`serverRequest` y `getResults` son variables declaradas como funciones ejecutadas por el último `console.log` donde todo comienza mandando dos parámetros
1. Un string constante
2. Una función callback que recibirá de parámetro `results`, pero para que funcione como callback en una sola linea debe ir sin parámetros.

Cuando se ejecuta `serverRequest` obtiene los dos parámetros pero concatena el string recibido con `"full"` para posteriormente mandarla como parámetro al callback, que en realidad es `getResults`

Al final es como si se ejecutara

```
getResults("The glass is half full!")
```

Y de ahi obtienes el parámetro para la función arrojando el siguiente resultado

```
"Response from the server: The glass is half full!"
```